# Red neurons - Acute neuronal injury

Tags: human-biology, neuroscience, pathology

> “Red neurons” are evident by about 12 to 24 hours after an irreversible hypoxic/ ischemic insult. The morphologic features consist of **shrinkage of the cell body**, pyknosis of the nucleus, disappearance of the nucleolus, and loss of Nissl substance, with intense eosinophilia of the cytoplasm.  -Robbins textbook of pathology

---

[Taken from Robbins pathologic basis of disease, 9e, pg.no1265, fig: 28-13B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnNQ9.jpg)

[image: Taken from Robbins pathologic basis of disease, 9e, pg.no1265, fig: 28-13B]

Why in case of neurons there is shrinkage instead of swelling as in other cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not some simple dichotomy of "neurons shrink and other cells swell" in response to hypoxia/ischemia.

Neuronal death can be necrotic or apoptotic or both, and at different stages different morphology is observed: generally swelling earlier, shrinkage later, though both are observed together early as well. Eosinophilia/"red neurons" tends to occur later as mentioned in this passage (after 6 hours, consistent with 12-24 hours) so that's probably why the author is referring mostly to shrinkage. Cells can also have swelling of some organelles, like mitochondria, despite shrinking overall.

Without further context of the passage you provided it's hard to say much more.

---

Garcia, J. H., Yoshida, Y., Chen, H., Li, Y., Zhang, Z. G., Lian, J. I. N. Y. I. N. G., ... & Chopp, M. (1993). Progression from ischemic injury to infarct following middle cerebral artery occlusion in the rat. The American journal of pathology, 142(2), 623.

Jenkins, L. W., Povlishock, J. T., Lewelt, W., Miller, J. D., & Becker, D. P. (1981). The role of postischemic recirculation in the development of ischemic neuronal injury following complete cerebral ischemia. Acta neuropathologica, 55(3), 205-220.

Portera‐Cailliau, C., Price, D. L., & Martin, L. J. (1997). Excitotoxic neuronal death in the immature brain is an apoptosis‐necrosis morphological continuum. Journal of Comparative Neurology, 378(1), 10-87.

Comment: Not much infiltration of phagocytes is seen in above figure. Shouldn't apoptotic cell need more phagocytes in close vicinity to immediately clear of the bits of cytoplasm which are shed off?

Comment: @JM97 Sorry I'm not sure what the answer to that question is for sure from the perspective of histopathology, just conceptually though I don't see any reason that absence of phagocytes demonstrates lack of apoptosis. Certainly microglia would be present to clean up at some point of healing but apoptosis itself can be initiated intrinsically.

Comment: There has to be something special as coagulative necrosis, a usual feature of ishcemia is not seen in CNS as given in chapter 2 of Robbins.

Answer (score -1):

Search for Exicitotoxic programed cell death. Acute Neuronal injury occur by this pathway. This is like Necroptosis. Cell shrinkage is seen due to Glutamate.  I have added some screenshots of my search,, rest you can search yourself. [image]
[image]
[image]
Read more at 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4398818/

Comment: @JM97, please do reply if this was helpful.

Comment: thanks for your efforts. I will certainly read excitotoxic cell death now. again thanks.